# Can a single player build a clan dojo?

Tags: warframe

Is it possible for an one-or-two-person clan to build a dojo? If so, what are the resources involved?

I'd like to experience the whole Dojo building experience so I don't plan to join an existing Clan with a dojo already.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it possible to do so. Though, it's really not recommended due to the resource costs involved.

To make (or access) the dojo itself, you must first create or join a clan. Then someone needs to make the Clan Key (the blueprint of this will be added to the player's foundry once they join a clan). The resources required are the following:

- 1    Morphic
- 500  Polymer Bundle
- 500  Ferrite
- 1500 Credits
- 12   Hours to build

Afterwards, the basic Clan Dojo, with a basic Clan hall as the starting room, is created. Now, resource costs for building other rooms (connectors, reactors, research facilities, etc.) are scaled depending on what clan size bracket you fall into (in this case, your supposed clan will fall into the Ghost Clan bracket - 1-10 members in total).

Yet still, they are quite expensive for a small number of players to handle, especially due to the usage of "rare" resources at higher levels (such as Forma). Unless you have a large stockpile of resources and credits, it's suggested to have at least 4-6 members to build a basic dojo with the important facilities. But, it's certainly doable with 1-2 people, though not recommended.

I strongly suggest you pay a visit to the [Warframe wiki page on Clan Dojos](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Dojo) for more information on each room type's costs, as well as for pre-planning the layout. Remember, you don't want to waste resources destroying and creating more rooms than necessary!

Comment: me and 2 other active friends have been building a massive dojo (shadow, all research labs, 8+ reactors, 3 clan halls, lots of research), so it is doable with a low amount of ppl.

Answer (score 7):

Yes it is definitely possible to do a fully functional and practical Dojo by yourself. The resources can be gathered quite "quickly", quickly in quotes, because research costs 3 days to do so you have three days to smartly farm for the next thing to buy.

For a fully functional, Research-aimed Dojo you need 15 Formae, you don't need to get them straight away, mind you, and I'm sure if you don't want to research specific stuff or want it to be not as pretty as to work as a real home for your future clan you can get less Formae and start away, I'd personally start the build at 2 Formae.

Here is how my Clan looks like, built by one person, farmed by one person and started around 75% of the research also by one person:

You start with a clan hall, with 2 doors, this hall is free and requires no forma. The first hallway I start with a Reactor, then I started building all the impractical stuff you don't need to visit or even see to have a functioning Dojo, my goal was the Grandest Clan Hall which gives you 6 free doors and AMPLE space for Trading posts and the 4 useful research centers.

Reactor -- Clan Hall -- Great Clan Hall -- Greater Clan Hall -- (T-Connector leading to an Oracle) -- Grand --(Cross Connector with two reactors) -- Elevator

So basically one long corridor with all the energy needs you have and the Oracle, a thoroughly useless room you need for research. Up until now you have used 10 Formae. The elevator is the starting point for the next bit

Elevator -- Grandest Clan Hall

Now you have 6 free doors, I put all 4 research centers, Tenno Lab, Energy Lab, Bio Lab and Chem Lab on the sides of the Grandest Hall, the front door leads to the elevator and the back door leads to a cross connector, and then an obstacle course and two free nodes. Everything behind the back door is up to you entirely.

Now make Grandest Clan Hall your home and you basically have a massive room with ALL research avaible :D

Answer (score 3):

Very possible.  I've built 65 rooms by myself.  If you enjoy playing the game and, as mentioned above, use your time wisely between builds it isn't that difficult.  Forma will become your biggest nightmare though.  Each room requires 1 and it takes ~ 20 minutes for even a chance of getting the blueprint for one.  This was basically a majority of my time on warframe, farming forma after forma on void runs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. I did. I built a full 100 room clan unlike any clan I`ve see in the whole game. Also decorated them to full capacity. Decoration was done by members but rooms were entirely done by me.

Answer (score 1):

100% can be done, we did it to get away from being constantly asked to play in the rails everyday. So just 4 of us and alot of mat's and forma, you will need a forma for every room. And we rushed rooms with plat also. We built one of the biggest dojo's I have seen for in that time. Put elevator going up to put your reactors in so everything you need is on the same level and have the grandest hall your main. Like all your research labs and trade and where to spawn etc. Just makes everything way more easy. Hope you's get it done.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is but def easier with more people. I'm doing this myself right now and as a fairly new player I've found all resources, no matter how rare, pretty easy to come by. The only exception to this (and the major roadblock you will encounter) is acquiring formas. These can be found in the Void, through alert missions or purchased for 20p. Asssuming you want to do this as cheaply as possible, I recommend finding a warframe that's good for solo play. Rhino and Loki come readily to mind. With a good solo warframe you'll be able to solo some of the void missions and with luck collect a few formas. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I made my clan by myself before I invited members so yes it's possible. But it cost a hell of resources, expansively Formas

Answer (score 0):

As leader of a Clan that was mostly made by me, I have to say it is possible, but everytime I work for my Clan Dojo I end up getting a lack of very common resources and credits, so it is possible, but not recommended.